# Как узнать дату вступления пользователя в группу VK?

Tags: vkontakte-api, вконтакте

Как узнать дату вступления пользователя в группу VK ?

Comment: Такой возможности не предоставляется, можно узнать только позицию вступления человека в группу.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если говорить о пользователях, которые уже вступили в сообщество, то — никак.

VK не предоставляет такой возможности в методе получения участников сообщества ([`groups.getMembers`](https://vk.com/dev/groups.getMembers)). Однако, если речь идет о личном сообществе, то, как вариант можно использовать `Callback API` или `Long Poll API` и отслеживать событие [`group_join`](https://vk.com/dev/groups_events) (вступления пользователя в группу). Затем обработка данных на своем сервере и занесение в базу данных.

Comment: Спасибо. Такая идея была, но были и опасения что я что-то упустил при чтении документации.

Comment: @Taypfpon, следовательно и нужно отследить событие выхода участника, чтобы знать его положение.